# google-app-script Pause for keyoared input/Arrowkey

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just wondering if there is a way to Pause script?

```
function test() {
  for (var c = 1; c < 6 ; c++) {
    var d = 'A'+c;
    var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(d).getValue();
    var valuep = valuep + "\\n"+ value ;
    Browser.msgBox(valuep);
    *** wait for "=>" key ***
  } 
}
```

Comment: To handle a pressed key event, no. Apps Script doesn't have a console to input.

Comment: Thank you, got it! will try luck with MS VBA!

Answer (score 1):

You can add `Utilities.sleep(time_in_ms)` to pause the execution of a Google Script.

Comment: Thank you, Wanted to add more hotkeys but thank you for the input. much appericated!

Answer (score 1):

`Browser.msgBox` automatically pauses server side script execution. As written in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgboxprompt),

> Note that this method causes the server-side script to be suspended.

Comment: Thank you, tried about, and tested little success but cannot add more hotkeys. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @user A [modal dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) html may be able to listen to key events. See [example html here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

Answer (score 0):

To handle a pressed key event, no. Apps Script doesn't have a console to input. – @Jescanellas